# How to open a React app from another React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, xmlhttprequest

From a React application, I'd like to request another React application and then load it in a new tab. The request contains authorization header, so that requirement prevents me from using a regular static link or a `window.open(link, '_blank');`, I need to use a proper request instead. What I am doing is fairly simple:

```
const handleClick = jwt => {
        fetch(url,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'text/html',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(body => {
                const w = window.open("");
                w.document.open();
                w.document.write(body);
                w.document.close();
            });
    };
```

That code opens a new tab and injects the HTML. However, what happens next is that the loaded index.html loads React files of the original opening application, instead of the opened app, and the result in new tab is simply the original app. The script tags that the index contains are the same for both applications, at least in development:

```
<script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/1.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/main.4bf234700064bd70611e.hot-update.js"></script> //this line differs ofc, but it is not important for the purpose of the question
```

Is there a way to force those new files to be downloaded from localhost:8000, which is the application I want to render, instead of localhost:4000, which is where my original app runs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is no. Browsers enforce something called "same-origin policy" to prevent you from doing things like XSS (cross site scripting attacks).

Otherwise you could theoretically do something like make a user's browser load facebook.com in a new tab with your little script file nested that automatically generates racist comments... or coinbase.com and triggers a transfer of Bitcoin if you happen to be a coinbase user and currently authenticated. etc.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

> Return value
>   A WindowProxy object, which is basically a thin wrapper for the Window object representing the newly created window, and has all its features available. If the window couldn't be opened, the returned value is instead null. The returned reference can be used to access properties and methods of the new window as long as it complies with Same-origin policy security requirements.

Comment: You are absolutely right and I knew about this. As the document at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy states, the origin is inherited for about:blank pages. But when I open the new tab like so `const w = window.open(url);`, it should presumably set the origin to localhost:8000, but it still won't work and no page is loaded.